# Error in assigning a turtle to a turtles-own variable

Tags: simulation, netlogo, multi-agent

I have a turtle whose cone of vision is defined to 5, 120. Now, I want the turtle to assign the nearest turtle with the same color as its friend. My code returns the error

```
this code can't be run by a patch
```

This is my code

```
turtles-own [ friend ] 

to-report checkForAttraction [ agent ]
  if [color] of one-of turtles-on empty-patches = [color] of agent [
    set friend min-one-of other turtles-on empty-patches with [color = [color] of agent ] [ distance myself ]
    set attracted? 1
  ]
  report actualVelocity
end
```

The error shows up at the

```
[color = [color] of agent ]
```

on the third line. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the offending line is that [`with`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#with) is parsed has having `empty-patches` as its *agentset* argument. And since patches don't have a `color` variable, you can't test `empty-patches` for `color = [color] of agent`, hence the error.

But you **don't** want to test `empty-patches` for that: you want to test `turtles-on empty-patches`!

And with some well placed parenthesis, you can:

```
set friend min-one-of other (turtles-on empty-patches) with [color = [color] of agent ] [ distance myself ]
```

Comment: I actually figured this out earlier on my own - it's amazing how NetLogo is so crazy about parentheses. But thank you!